# How to use $ as well as jQuery

Tags: jquery, opencart

I have an opencart project where I have used `$('#some-id')` as well as `jQuery('#some-id')` which was working perfect, But after upgrading project from 1.5 to 2.1, its only accepting `jQuery('#some-id')` and throwing error for `$('#some-id')` as

> TypeError: $(...) is null

following is my one of the hundred sample ajax function.

```
    $('#button-coupon').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=total/coupon/coupon',
            type: 'post',

/*Here $ is not working jQuery works. Not just here, but in each line where $ is used its throwing error, untill & unless I replace it with jQuery.*/
            data: 'coupon=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'coupon\']').val()),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there any way to get both of them work. I don't want to waste time in replacing **$** with **jQuery**?

Following is the snapshot of error in firebug console.

[image]

If I change `$('input[name=\'coupon\']')` to `jQuery('input[name=\'coupon\']')` than it moves to some other line where **$** is used. for example see below image.

[image: next error after replacing $ with jQuery in above line.]

I have tried to use latest as well as old versions of jQuery, but my problem still persists.

Comment: Certainly this is possible, but you need to specify more details. 1. the exact error message you get and 2. the structure of your files.

Comment: @arkascha, please see uploaded error pic.

Comment: There is something that overrides `$` after jquery declaration

Comment: The default state is that if `jQuery` works than `$` works as well. If it doesn't, then you've done something to break it. We can't tell what because you haven't shown any significant piece of your code.

Comment: can you give me some possible hint about its breaking reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not include any information about your code this is just a general hint, but probably worth diving into for you:

What is typically done when trying to prevent conflicts between different JS frameworks and libraries (all using the `$` shortcut) is to encapsulate your own library or modules that way:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    // your library or modules here
})(jQuery);
```

That way the identifier `jQuery` has to be specified only once, outside your own code, when the definition is "self calling" itself right away. Inside that block the jQuery library is now known under the shortcut `$` again, but it does *not* collide with other usages of that shortcut *outside* that code block any more.

This is a compilation of hints about that topic:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Where am I supposed to write this?

Comment: You encapsulate your code by that. So basically you hide all of your code definition away in a function that is executed once right away with a single argument: jQuery. That way you "inject" jQuery into the wrapping function where it is called `$` again. Variables defined inside the scope of a function are not visible globally. That is why you have no collision any more but can still use the `$` inside your code.

Comment: Yes, that is a typical event handler function based on the jQuery library. As said: wrap it, so that it is not defined in the global name space where you have the collision. What is the problem with doing that?

Comment: I have 1000 similar functions in my project. I cant wrap-em all.

Comment: You put them all inside the one wrapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107946/discussion-between-mujahed-akas-and-arkascha).

Comment: Just a short compilation of the situation as presented in the chat: turned out that the JS code could not be wrapped this way, since it was implemented as 1000 separate functions all buried inline in php files. With such an architecture it indeed is not possible to follow this clean approach. We failed to find a solution for that borked situation.